# asp.net core and depenency injection example what about poco classes as return types

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Looking over the DI section from the docs here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1

So using their example below, what if in my Repository, I wanted to return a POCO object of some sort.  Wouldn't that have to be registered in configureservices also?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DependencyInjectionSample.Models;

    namespace DependencyInjectionSample.Interfaces
    {
        public interface ICharacterRepository
        {
            IEnumerable<Character> ListAll();
            void Add(Character character);
        }
    }

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using DependencyInjectionSample.Interfaces;

    namespace DependencyInjectionSample.Models
    {
        public class CharacterRepository : ICharacterRepository
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

            public CharacterRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
            {
                _dbContext = dbContext;
            }

            public IEnumerable<Character> ListAll()
            {
                return _dbContext.Characters.AsEnumerable();
            }

            public void Add(Character character)
            {
                _dbContext.Characters.Add(character);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase()
        );

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Register application services.
        services.AddScoped<ICharacterRepository, CharacterRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
        services.AddScoped<IOperationScoped, Operation>();
        services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingleton, Operation>();
        services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingletonInstance>(new Operation(Guid.Empty));
        services.AddTransient<OperationService, OperationService>();
    }
```

Comment: No you do not need to. Are you having an issue with that approach ? Which class are you talking about ?

Comment: Not having an issue, at least not yet.  I am building a new class library to use with an asp.net core api project.  Im splitting my classes up in a way so as to use the repository pattern.  Each of my respository classes will have methods that return POCO objects, rather than EF entities. I think my confusion is with the repository pattern, rather than DI setup with configureservices.

Comment: @Shyju - wont the POCO classes be considered a dependency?

Comment: Those are just DTOs to transfer data. Do not complicate POCOs.

Comment: To understand more about DI, you should read freely available [the introductory chapter](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition/chapter-1) of [Dependency Injection in .NET, second edition](https://manning.com/seemann2). That chapter has a section on "What to inject and what not to inject".